# Can we configure SSO (Single Sign On) in Azure without using Azure Active Directory?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

Can we configure SSO (Single Sign-On) in Azure without using the Azure Active Directory? Or using any Code.

Comment: Why *not* use Azure AD? What have you tried yourself to get to an answer? As is, this post is no fit for SO. Please refer to [ask].

Comment: No matter one line question on a paragraph ! The requirement is same. I believe that the simple answer posted by other user below is more than enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to log in with Azure AD users then [SSO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/what-is-single-sign-on) is required for Azure AD. If you have your own database of users to login and then you don't require Azure AD.